# Como salvar uma imagem da galeria e carregar na activity?

Tags: android, imagem, galeria

Gostaria de saber como salvar uma imagem da galeria e carregar na activity na versão 2.3.3 do emulador do Eclipse, pois meu código só funciona quando testo no meu dispositivo Android 4.1 e mesmo assim quando carrego uma imagem grande ele deixa um enorme espaço em branco na parte de cima e de baixo da imagem.

Meu código segue abaixo:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    Log.i("AQUI!", "Entrou no onActivityResult");
    //Detects request codes
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("AQUI!", "Entrou no IF");
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                Log.i("AQUI!", "Bitmap recebeu a imagem");
                imguser.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar) {
        String filename = "profile.jpg";
        // cria o arquivo
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");            
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 500);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 500);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", false);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Ao rodar no emulador recebo o seguinte erro de Log:

```
01-23 18:31:36.146: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=file:///mnt/sdcard/profile.jpg (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.meuapp/com.example.meuapp.atividades.EditarContaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Graças aos Log.i's que usei no meu código descobri que o erro esta nesta linha:

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
```

O `this.getContentResolver()` esta retornando `null`, mas esse erro só ocorre no emulador Android 2.3.3, já no meu dispositivo(Android 4.1) ele roda normal.

Comment: Tem a certeza que é `getContentResolver()` que retorna null? Não será `selectedImage` que é null?.

Comment: @ramaral Pois é fiz um teste aqui e não é o getContentResolver() que retorna null, porém fui tentar fazer um teste pra ver o selectedImage retorna null não tive secusso, coloquei um if(selectedImage == null) e não executa o que está no if(). Ao comentar a linha:  cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");  ele funciona, mas preciso cortar a imagem e definir um tamanho fixo.

Comment: @ramaral O problema que percebo é que ele não consegue criar e salvar um arquivo mesmo com a permissão <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  no AndroidManifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, pessoal problema resolvido por completo, agora ele não causa nenhum erro e as imagens são apresentadas exatamente no mesmo tamanho que a imagem anterior tinha antes. Claro que o código ainda não está bem estruturado, mas serve como base para resolver um problema como este. Nesta minha solução eu add no AndroidManifest a permissão: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`. E incluir uma lógica para saber se tenho permissão para ler e salvar arquivos. Para os espaços em branco eu usei um atributo no xml da imageview que é: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`. E para deixar as imagens carregadas com o mesmo tamanho da anterior eu reconfigurei os parâmetros de layout da imageview pegando da prória imageview e setando novamente como um valor absoluto, pois antes era "WRAP_CONTENT". Segue a baixo minha solução espero que ajuda alguém ou alguém ajude a melhorar ela.

```
public class EditarContaActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;    
Button btneditar1;
File file;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    imguser = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgdefault_user);

    btneditar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btneditar);
    btneditar1.setOnClickListener(this);      

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_editarconta, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    //Detects request codes
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Log.i("AQUI!", "Entrou no IF");
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
        Log.i("AQUI!", "Bitmap recebeu a imagem");  

        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);  
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        int largura = imguser.getWidth();
        int altura = largura;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams margens = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imguser.getLayoutParams();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(largura, altura);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        params.setMargins(0, margens.topMargin, 0, 0);
        imguser.setLayoutParams(params);
        imguser.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub        

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btneditar) {
        boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false; 
        boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false; 
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) { 
            // Podemos ler e escrever os meios de comunicação 
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true; 
            Log.i("PERMISSÂO", "Podemos ler e escrever os meios de comunicação");
        } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) { 
            // Só podemos ler a mídia 
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true; 
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false; 
            Log.i("PERMISSÂO", "Só podemos ler a mídia");
        } else { 
            // Outra coisa que está errada. Pode ser um de muitos outros estados, mas tudo o que precisamos 
            // Para saber é que não podemos ler nem escrever 
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false; 
            Log.i("PERMISSÂO", "Não podemos ler nem escrever");
        }

        String filename = "profile.jpg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);


        Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");            
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    }

}
```